# Like & unlike voting system with PHP issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css

I have a profile page and under my photo i have a like button with a counter and i want when i hit like, the text for like button to be setted with "unlike" but the counter to stay there with all like's that profile page have from all the users & when i hit unlike to take my like back.

I'm begginer and i messed-up with the code, so please help, i will apreciate,thanks!

This is what i have so far: likes.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.like', function(){
        if($(this).attr('title') == 'Like'){
            $that = $(this);
            $.post('action.php', {id:$(this).attr('id'), action:'like'},function(){
            $that.text('Unlike');
            $that.attr('title','Unlike');
            });
        }else{
            if($(this).attr('title') == 'Unlike'){
                $that = $(this);
                $.post('action.php', {id:$(this).attr('id'), action:'unlike'},function(){
                    $that.text('Like');
                    $that.attr('title','Like');
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Php count process file:

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
$id=$user->filter->id; //User id
$sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE id=?");
$sql->execute(array($id));
if($sql->rowCount()==1){
    echo '<div class='btn btn-warning like' id="'.$id.'" title="Unlike" style='margin-top: -6px; title="Like"'> Like <span class='like-count'>0</span></div>';
}else{ 
    echo '<div class='btn btn-warning like' title="Like" style='margin-top: -6px;'> Like <span class='like-count'>0</span></div>';
}
?>
```

action.php file:

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";

$id=$user->filter->id;
$action=$_POST['action'];
if ($action=='like'){
    $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE id=?");
    $sql->execute(array($id));
    $matches=$sql->rowCount();
    if($matches==0){
        $sql=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO likes (id) VALUES(?)");
        $sql->execute(array($id));
        $sql=$dbh->prepare("UPDATE likes SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id=?");
        $sql->execute(array($id));
    }else{
        die("There is No profile With That ID");
    }
}
if ($action=='unlike'){
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM `likes` WHERE id=?");
    $sql->execute(array($id));
    $matches = $sql->rowCount();
    if ($matches != 0){
        $sql=$dbh->prepare("UPDATE likes SET likes=likes-1 WHERE id=?");
        $sql->execute(array($id));
    }
}
?>
```

```css
.like-count {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 2px 12px 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    color:white;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fff),to(#e6e6e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff',endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6',GradientType=0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.btn-warning {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    background-color: #faa732;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fbb450,#f89406);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fbb450),to(#f89406));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fbb450,#f89406);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fbb450,#f89406);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fbb450,#f89406);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #f89406 #f89406 #ad6704;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fffbb450',endColorstr='#fff89406',GradientType=0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}
```

```html
<div class='btn btn-warning like' style='margin-top: -6px;'> Like <span class='like-count'>0</span></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue.

Comment: is not working...when i like the page in the db table i have no like only "-1", and the button is messing-up, the black counter is disapear when i like the page

Comment: Where is your item with the class "like" that jquery is running the click function for?

Comment: While here's a syntax error `echo '<div class='btn` so you must not be checking for errors. How are you going to `update` after you `delete` the record? `$sql=$dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM likes WHERE id=?");
 $sql->execute(array($id));
 $sql=$dbh->prepare("UPDATE likes SET likes=likes-1 WHERE id=?");`

Comment: is messed-up... i'm new with this...that's why i'm asking for help.. :)

Comment: Look at your error logs and enable error reporting. You can't use the same quote type for the PHP encapsulation as you use in the string. All uses of that quote type in the string must be escaped with a backslash or just changed to the other quote type.

Comment: As @SgtAJ points out... the jquery -- `.on('click', '.like',` is looking for the `.like` class, which does *not* appear *anywhere* in your HTML. So, there's *nothing* for the jquery to act upon.

Comment: Indeed i have inserted the like class, and is working but the black counter is disappearing after i hit the like button and shows me only the like&unlike without the counter, i think the problem is from js file at $that.text('Unlike');

Comment: Show us your updated code, to include the `like` class that your jquery is catching the click for, if you still want help.

Comment: i have updated the script, the counter is not working and is disapear..